# can Android spinner have text/images in list, yet only text when closed?

Tags: android, spinner

I need my Android spinner to show a text and images when the selections are displayed, yet show only text when the spinner is closed. Is this possible?

Comment: Show us some code of what you've tried and why it failed.

Answer (score 0):

create custom item for spinner.
see this tutorial : 
[HOW TO CREATE CUSTOM SPINNER CONTROL IN ANDROID](http://custom-android-dn.blogspot.nl/2012/12/how-to-use-and-custom-spinner-control.html) .